# JQuery: Change Buttons behavior

Tags: jquery, css, button

I am new to jquery and having issues making a function which does the following.

I have  table with three rows and four columns each. Inside each column, I have a button with a seperate css for hover effects. The idea of each button is to show their value in a textbox when the button is pressed.

I have tried different ways to do the following but have been unsuccessful.

1. Change the css of the pressed button (say change color to red) and make all the other buttons change back to original color (say yellow).
2. add the value of the button in the text box.

It is an aspx page so I even tried getting the value by calling the target if of the button. for example:

**JS:**

```
//Div Specific Function
$("#step1").click(function (e) {
    var thisID = e.target.ty;
    $('#input').data('btnType', 'Amount').each(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('button');
    })

    $(thisID).toggleClass('button-hover');

});
```

**html**

```
<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="90%">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="button" data-btnType="Amount" id="btn50" runat="server" value=" $50" Text="$50"  class="button" />
  </td>
  <td>
   <input type="button" data-btnType="Amount" id="btn100" runat="server" value="$100" Text="$100" class="button"  />
  </td>
  <td>
   <input type="button" data-btnType="Amount" id="btn150" runat="server" Text="$150" value="$150" class="button"  />
  </td>
  <td>
   <input type="button" data-btnType="Amount" id="btn200" runat="server" Text="$200" value="$200" class="button"  />
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

How can I make these buttons act like a radio effect. Please note that there are 10 buttons in all in this div.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$("table :button").click(function() {
  $("table :button").removeClass("selected").addClass("unselected");
  $(this).removeClass("unselected").addClass("selected");
  $("#textBox").val($(this).val());
});
```

// I have changed your html little, added class unselected in your html code

jsfiddle example:

> http://jsfiddle.net/k3J2r/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    $(".red").removeClass("red").addClass("yellow"); // remove the prev pressed button class
    $(this).removeClass("yellow").addClass("red");      // add the red css class to  pressed button
    $(".button").not(".red").addClass("yellow"); // add to all other buttons yellow class
    $("#textBox").val($(this).val());    // get val of pressed button val
});
```

Comment: Hi mdvlpr. Thanks for the reply. I tried your solution but it didnt work. here is the snippet of what my js file looks like:

$("#step1").click(function () { //called only for the buttons in this div
        $('.button').click(function () { //I could not understand what the .red was for
            $(this).addClass("button.hover");
            $('button :not(cng-button)').toggleClass('cng-button');

            $("input[name='txtOtherAmount']").val($(this).val()); //the value is not copied to the textbox either
        })

    });


I apologise if this causes any inconvenience.